# Responsive image (srcset + sizes) does not scale when switching from portrait to landscape on mobile

Tags: orientation, responsive-images, srcset

My image looks like this:

```
<img 
src="{image_url}/image.jpg" 
width="100%" 
alt="Image" 
srcset="
{image_url}/image-375w.jpg 375w, 
{image_url}/image-414w.jpg 414w, 
{image_url}/image-768w.jpg 768w, 
{image_url}/image-834w.jpg 834w, 
{image_url}/image-1024w.jpg 1024w, 
{image_url}/image-1440w.jpg 1440w, 
{image_url}/image-1920w.jpg 1920w, 
{image_url}/image-6000w.jpg 6000w
" 
sizes="
(min-width: 980px) 980px, 
100vw
">
```

With the following style:

```
img {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 980px;
    height: auto;
}
```

Now when you take your physical iPhone 11 in portrait mode and you visit the website you will notice it will load the proper image. In my case 414px width x2 resolution is 828 pixels and so it will show the image `image-834w.jpg`.

However when I will now turn my phone 90 degrees to landscape, it becomes 896px width x2 resolutions is 1.792px, but it will not update the image to this new resolution. It will keep `image-834w.jpg` resulting in a blurry image. Only when you refresh the page in landscape it will show the proper image, `image-1920w.jpg`.

What I would expect is that up to 979px it will use 100% of the viewport width to determine the best image from the srcset to present. From 980px and up it will never present an image larger then 980px. (not taking retina into account for simplicity reasons).

---

*(edited:06-06-2020 14:00)*

So I noticed somehow the sizes need to be extensive.

```
(min-width:980px) 980px, 
(min-width:835px) 100vw, 
(min-width:769px) 100vw, 
(min-width:415px) 100vw, 
(min-width:376px) 100vw, 
(max-width:374px) 100vw, 
100vw
```